# Sharepoint 2007 Event ID 6482

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Our two server SharePoint 2007 SP2 farm has an issue.  Event ID 6482 appears in the Application log of the Web front end many times a day. Often many time a minute.

The full error is from Office SharePoint Server

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Office SharePoint Server
Event Category: Office Server Shared Services 
Event ID:   6482
Date:       11/12/2009
Time:       3:05:22 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   XXXXXX
Description:
Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance (36a9b7ef-59aa-4f94-8887-8bf7b56f2f91).

Reason: Error during encryption or decryption. System error code 0.

Techinal Support Details:
System.ArgumentException: Error during encryption or decryption. System error code 0.
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.SynchronizeDefaultContentSource(IDictionary applications)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerJob.ProvisionLocalSharedServiceInstances(Boolean isAdministrationServiceJob)

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

The SharePoint site appears to be functioning normally and Search returns expected results.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Found this tip from MS.  Avoids the mess of password resets. Unfortunately, errors return after a few minutes

Before trying to reset the password, you could try to clear SharePoint configuration cache on all your SharePoint servers and see if it is helpful for your issue. To clear SharePoint configuration caches, please follow the steps:

1. Stop Windows SharePoint Services Timer in Services.
2. Locate the configuration cache folder in `%allusersprofile%\Application Data\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\GUID`
   In Windows Server 2008, the configuration cache is in the following location: `%allusersprofile%\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\GUID`
3. Back up the Cache.ini file.
4. Delete all the XML configuration files in the GUID folder.
5. Edit the Cache.ini file. Change the content to 1, and then click Save the changes.
6. Start Windows SharePoint Services Timer in Services.
   See KB 939308 ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939308 ) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the server is using cached credentials. Did you just change the password for a service account? Assuming so, did you use stsadm to make the change?

[KB 934828](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/934838) outlines how (note the extra 2 steps if you're running in a least-privilege setup)

Comment: Thanks Vinny.  We will check that but credentials have not changed

Comment: Hmm. Anything interesting under the CA location below?

Central Administration > Application Management > Check Services Enabled in this Farm

Comment: No issues reported there